# Deploy Azure Function with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy Azure Function with ARM template , but I am not able to create the function itself. Is it possible to create the actual function using ARM template?

I have zipped the source code for the function and placed it in a public location, I have added the MSBuild section to the template and although the deployment finished successfully - the App function was created but not the function itself

here is the template

```
{
"parameters": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "storageName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "subscriptionId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "storage_account_endpoint": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                        "value": "node"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "~2"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                        "value": "[concat(toLower(parameters('name')), 'bd58')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                        "value": "8.11.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "storage_account_connection",
                        "value": "[parameters('storage_account_endpoint')]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
            "reserved": false
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName'))]"
        ],
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "MSDeploy",
                "type": "Extensions",
                "apiVersion": "2015-02-01",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('name'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "packageUri": "<URL to zip>"
                }
            }
        ],
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
        "kind": "functionapp"
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
        }
    }
],
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Did you zip the folder of your code, and not just the contents?  See http://mythoughtlab.azurewebsites.net/azure/deploying-your-azure-function-via-arm-template/

Comment: yes - this is exactly what I did

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short No - ARM can only create the infrastructure for you but not deploy the code (**see comment).
But as always there is a way. A while back MS release a new feature 'Run from ZIP' on web apps (including Function Apps). All you need is the actual project (code published as ZIP) to be in a location where the function app can access it.

We use VSTS (Azure Dev Ops) for CI/CD. So we build the solution add the ZIP to the artifact. Then in the Release we copy the ZIP to blob storage, create a SAS Token and pass the location of the blob Container with the SAS Token to ARM. In the ARM template we build the connection string to the ZIP, using input parameter. As soon as ARM is done then the Function is up and running.

Eg.

```
{ 
"parameters": {
"name": {
    "type": "string"
},
"storageName": {
    "type": "string"
},
"location": {
    "type": "string"
},
"subscriptionId": {
    "type": "string"
},
"storage_account_endpoint": {
    "type": "string"
},
 "artifactsUri": {
  "type": "string"
},
"artifactsBlobContainer": {
  "type": "string"
},    
"artifactsLocationSasToken": {
  "type": "string"
}
},
"resources": [
{
    "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                    "value": "node"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                    "value": "~2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                    "value": "[concat(toLower(parameters('name')), 'bd58')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                    "value": "8.11.1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "storage_account_connection",
                    "value": "[parameters('storage_account_endpoint')]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP",
                  "value": "[concat(parameters('artifactsUri'), '/', parameters('artifactsBlobContainer'),'/','blahbla.FA.zip',parameters('artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
                }
            ]
        },
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "reserved": false
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName'))]"
    ],
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "MSDeploy",
            "type": "Extensions",
            "apiVersion": "2015-02-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "packageUri": "<URL to zip>"
            }
        }
    ],
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
    },
    "kind": "functionapp"
},
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
    }
}
],
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
}
```

'Run from ZIP' is achieved with the 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP' app setting.
Hope this helps

Comment: arm templates can deploy code for you if you put the code inline in a files:{...} field

Comment: We might be able to deploy via the template now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code. See resource of type `sourcecontrols`. You can specify a RepoUrl and a Branch.

Comment: I think it's now `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

Answer (score 3):

I just use this [FunctionWebDeploy.json](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/0c5a95ce5f0fdff7d4360b986059c7954d52ea68/ARMTemplates/FunctionsWebDeploy.json#L53-L65) template. I download the app content（zip file）from the existing function app and upload it to the public address. Finally I can deploy function app including code.

[image]

Comment: But how do you ensure security if the uploaded zip file is accessible publicly? I'm assuming you are uploading to storage space and using a url to access it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Azure portal portal.azure.com, and create a new Azure Function.

[image]

2.Go to Resource Group.
3.Go to Export template.
4.You will see something like this.

This is the ARM Template for all resources/componets.

[image]